# Mounting a linux image built with "dd" on Mac OSX 10.7

Tags: mac-osx, filesystems, migration, dd, disk-image

I recently did a

```
ssh root@myserver "dd if=/dev/xvda " | dd of=/<localpath>/myimage.img
```

as instructed by my VPS server docs at linode. I did this before to another linux system and mounted it perfectly by doing

```
sudo mount -o loop myimage.img mountdirectory
```

But on my mac osx 10.7 I get the following error.

```
mount: You must specify a filesystem type with -t.
```

I tried -t ext, -t ext3, -t ext4 but all failed with an error like this

```
mount: exec /System/Library/Filesystems/ext4.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_ext4 for /<mount directory>: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Mac OS X isn't Linux - the supported filesystems are completely different.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29842/how-can-i-mount-an-ext4-file-system-on-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get VirtualBox and install Ubuntu on it. Pass the .img file to the VM as a disk. Edit the fstab in the VM to mount the disk image.

Answer (score 2):

Shamelessly stolen from [the answer on this Ask Different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29842/how-can-i-mount-an-ext4-file-system-on-os-x)

---

The answer depends on the OS X version you are running:

**If you are running 10.5 (Leopard) or 10.6 (Snow Leopard)**, [Paragon’s ExtFS driver](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/) (commercial) will give you read and write access to ext2 / ext3 / ext4 file systems. Paragon [does not list Lion as a compatible OS](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/features.html#2) for the ExtFS driver version current as of November 1st, 2011, 8.0, and considering that the NTFS driver, which shares the same core, [has been updated to version 9 for Lion compatibility](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/release.html), I’d suspect this is for a good reason.

**If you are running 10.7 (Lion) and can’t wait (or don’t feel like investing into commercial software)**, you can setup a Linux virtual machine, mount your volume(s) there and share it / them via [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) or (S)FTP. [This post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mac-os-x-read-ext3-ext4-external-usb-hard-disk-partition/) has some details on how to achieve this using the free [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). Note this is not exactly a lightweight solution, even if using a [prebuilt VirtualBox VM](http://virtualboxes.org/images/) will spare you installing and configuring a Linux distro from scratch.